# How to stop the DMA transfer when it reaches end of the buffer?

Tags: stm32, dma

I want to mimic the "double buffer mode" without using it (because I don't want to deal with the error conditions, plus, I didn't really understand how it works) so I need to

1. Start DMA transfer in circular mode
2. Stop the transfer when my other buffer is ready
3. Change the source data pointer
4. Restart the DMA transfer.

I can do pretty much what I needed to do with the following code:

```c
/*
 * dma-gpio.c
 *
 * author: Cerem Cem ASLAN
 * reference: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W000003yufESAQ/how-to-setup-dma-to-gpio-transfer-using-hal-in-the-cubeidemy-goal-is-to-transfer-the-contents-of-an-integer-array-8-bits-per-value-to-8-gpio-pins
 * description:
 *   DMA memory to GPIO transfer example that transfers 256 bytes of data.
 *   GPIO registers are just another are of memory. This example uses 
 *   Peripheral-to-memory feature in circular mode. 
 *
 * Setup:
 *   1. Enable DMA2 clock from AHBENR register (bit22)
 *   2. Disable any ongoing dma transfers and make sure it is ended
 *   3. Set data direction to memory-to-peripheral
 *   4. Choose an appropriate channel using CHSEL bit in order to use TIM1_UP event.
 *   5. Choose increment mode for memory register (MINC)
 *   6. Choose increment size MSIZE (half word)
 *   7. Set source/destination memory addresses M0AR/PAR
 *   8. Set number of items to be transferred NDTR
 *   9. Set priority PL
 *   10. Setup TIM1
 *   11. Fire dma transfer by starting TIM1
 * 
 */

#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "system_stm32f4xx.h"

/*************************************************
* function declarations
*************************************************/
int main(void);

#define BUF_SIZE 256
uint16_t dma_buf[BUF_SIZE];

// Create a pointer at source and destination addresses
volatile uint16_t *src_addr = (uint16_t *) dma_buf;
volatile uint16_t *dst_addr = (uint16_t *) &GPIOE->ODR;

void configure_dma_transfer(){
    /********************************
     * setup DMA
     * (RM: 10.5.5 DMA stream x configuration register (DMA_SxCR))
     * 
     * Refer to include/stm32f407xx.h header for constant definitions
     *******************************/

    // enable DMA2 clock, bit 22 on AHB1ENR
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN;     // enable DMA2
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_TIM1EN;        // enable TIM1

    // We will use TIM1_UP so we are using DMA2_Stream5, see RM: Table 43. DMA2 request mapping

    // clear DMA Stream configuration register
    // single transfer, M0 is target, single buffer mode, circular buffer disabled
    DMA2_Stream5->CR = 0;
    // wait until dma is disabled
    while(DMA2_Stream5->CR & (1 << 0));


    DMA2_Stream5->CR =
        (6u << DMA_SxCR_CHSEL_Pos) | // select channel 6, see Table 43. DMA2 request mapping in the reference manual
        DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_0           | // 0b01:memory data size 16 bit
        DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_0           | // 0b01:peripheral data size 16 bit
        DMA_SxCR_MINC              | // memory increment
        DMA_SxCR_DIR_0             | // 0b01: memory to peripheral
        0;

    // set channel priority PL bits17:16 to medium
    DMA2_Stream5->CR |= (0x1 << 16);

    // enable circular mode 
    DMA2_Stream5->CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC; 

    // source memory address
    DMA2_Stream5->M0AR = (uint32_t) src_addr;
    // destination peripheral address
    DMA2_Stream5->PAR = (uint32_t) dst_addr;
    // number of items to be transferred
    DMA2_Stream5->NDTR = BUF_SIZE;

    // enable DMA channel
    DMA2_Stream5->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;

    #define APB2_BUS_FREQ 168               // MHz
    TIM1->ARR = (APB2_BUS_FREQ / 4) - 1;    // Generate 4 MHz events
    TIM1->BDTR = TIM_BDTR_MOE;              // required on advanced timers
    TIM1->DIER = TIM_DIER_UDE;              // enable DMA on timer update (overflow)
}

void start_dma_transfer(){
    TIM1->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN;   // start the timer
}

/*************************************************
* main code starts from here
*************************************************/
int main(void)
{
    set_sysclk_to_168();
    /********************************
     * setup output - GPIOE 12,13,14,15
     *******************************/
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOEEN;
    GPIOE->MODER &= ~(0xFFU << 24);
    GPIOE->MODER |= (0x55 << 24);

    configure_dma_transfer();

    // Fill src_addr with numbers
    // Leave GPIOE_8 LOW, toggle the others. Set GPIOE_8 only at the end of buffer
    // to see if we could really stop the DMA transfer correctly.
    uint16_t x[2] = {0xefff, 0x0000}; 
    for (int i=0; i<BUF_SIZE; i++){
        src_addr[i] = x[i%2];
        if (i == BUF_SIZE-1){
            // last element
            src_addr[i] |= 0x1000;
        }
    }

    //DMA2_Stream5->CR |= DMA_SxCR_TCIE; // enable transfer complete interrupt
    //NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream5_IRQn);

    start_dma_transfer();
    
    // Disable circular mode after "some time" (after my other buffer is ready)
    delay();
    DMA2_Stream5->CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC; // disable circular mode

    while(1)
    {
    }
}

void delay(){
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++);
}

void DMA2_Stream5_IRQHandler(){
}
```

I run this code on STM32F407VG. Here is the logic analyzer output:

[image]

What I expect is a continuous square wave at the `CLK` pin and a single `HIGH` state on `SYNC` pin.

What I get is a little bit different: DMA transfer continues roughly 22 times after I disable the circular mode with `DMA2_Stream5->CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;` line.

I also tried to stop the DMA inside the "end of transfer interrupt", with no luck.

How can I make DMA stop after it reaches exactly the end of its buffer?

Comment: _"DMA transfer continues roughly **22 times after I disable** the circular mode with DMA2_Stream5->CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC; line"_ - how do you know this?

Comment: I disabled the DMA in its interrupt handler. The handler is fired when the transfer is completed, which is also indicated by the `SYNC PIN` as I toggled that pin as the last action, I expect no more toggles on the `CLK_PIN` after `SYNC_PIN` toggles. I counted the toggles on `CLK_PIN` after `SYNC_PIN` toggles and it was 22.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. Your code has a delay loop with unknown execution time after starting the DMA transfer, followed by disabling circular mode. How do you know exactly when the disable operation occurred? Why should it have any relationship to the 'sync_pin' signal?   _"I disabled the DMA in its interrupt handler. The handler is fired when the transfer is completed,"_ - but your code shows an empty interrupt handler, and DMA interrupts not enabled?

Comment: simply do not  make it circular